# Replace special characters with alphabet in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, regex

How to remove Special Character and alphabet from variable by jQuery.

I have

```
var test = +985
```

But I want to get value as

```
var another = 985
```

It should not allow character as well + as I am using it in Phone Code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

try to something like this...

```
var inputString = "~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}[]|\:;'<>,./?Some actual text to keep, maybe...",
var outputString = inputString.replace(/([~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,.\/? ])+/g, '-').replace(/^(-)+|(-)+$/g,'');
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

You just need to use replace function it's first parameter is symbol you want to replace and another is symbol or word you want to replace with.

For more info please visit [Javascript replace function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

> var test = "+985"; 
>   var another = test.replace("+", "");

Answer (score 1):

Try this to extract number:

```
var test = +985;
alert(test+"".match(/\d+/));
```